# Cannot pass a List<Foo> to a method expecting a List<IFoo>, where Foo : IFoo

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, casting

I have a class `Foo` implementing the `IFoo` interface. I have a method taking a `List<IFoo>` as a parameter. However, it cannot convert from `List<Foo>` to `List<IFoo>` - this surprises me, since `Foo` implements the `IFoo` interface.

How can I get around this, and why does this occur? (Always good to learn from mistakes)

Comment: You're going to need to share the code I think. If your method accepts List<IFoo> and your object Foo implements IFoo then that's perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. I added the comment before refreshing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `List<T>` is not covariant.  For details, see [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

If you can make your method work on `IEnumerable<T>` instead, this will work (you can pass `List<Foo>` into `IEnumerable<IFoo>` in .NET 4, since it's defined `IEnumerable<out T>`).

The reason `List<T>` is not covariant, btw, is because it's not defining a read only contract.  Since `List<T>` explicitly allows you to add elements (via `Add(T)`), it's not safe to allow covariance to work.  If this was allowed, the method would expect to be able to add an element of type `Bar` (if `Bar` derives from `IFoo`) to the list, but that would fail, since the list is *really* a `List<Foo>`, not a `List<IFoo>`.  Since `IEnumerable<T>` only allows you to iterate through the list, but not modify it, it can be covariant and just work as expected in this case.

Comment: This was very useful; thanks! I replaced the parameter definition(?) with `IEnumerable<IFoo>` and the errors went; however, is there any chance of hidden bugs by doing this? I'd prefer to reach a solid solution than just hiding errors..(I am just iterating the list and calling method `Bar`)

Comment: @The Communist Duck: Nope.  That's why `IEnumerable<out T>` has the "out" in the definition.  It's perfectly safe to use an IEnumerable with covariance, as you're doing here.  As long as you're iterating, this works perfectly (which is why the language now supports it!)

Answer (score 8):

Believe it or not, this is not typesafe.

Consider the following code:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
List<IFoo> iFooList = fooList;    //Illegal

iFooList.Add(new SomeOtherFoo()); //That's not Foo!
```

You're asking for a *covariant* conversion; that's only possible for immutable types.
In addition, .Net only supports covariance for interfaces.

Change the method to take an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there is NO inheritence or implementation relationship between specializations of a generic type.  `List<Foo>` does not inherit from `List<IFoo>` in any way. It's like comparing `string` to `int`.

This is not to say there is no relationship between the types at all; just that the relationship in question is not inheritance.  Instead, we have a ***specialization*** relationship between the two types.  Certain types in .Net 4.0 and later support an attribute of specialization known as **covariance**.  [Co- and contra- variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) allow the specialized portion of a generic type to *vary* (note the root word there) under certain circumstances.  `List<T>` is not one of those types.

But what I would do in this case (where I don't know for sure you have .Net 4.0) is make the whole method generic:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : IFoo
{
    //...
}
```

Note that I also used `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`.  You should still be able to pass lists to this function, because there is an inheritance/implementation relationship between `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>`.  You can also process arrays and any other supported sequence.  IEnumerable is also one of the types that supports covariance.  Just about any method that requires a `List<T>` argument should be updated to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4, this doesn't need to be generic.  Just using `public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<IFoo> items)` will work due to the fact that `IEnumerable<out T>` is already a covariant interface.  This is an option for in .NET 2-3.5, though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new `List<IFoo>` and add all the items from the first list to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can convert it to new list declared as `List<IFoo>` which is what you need like so:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

theMethodThatTakesIFooList(list.ToList<IFoo>());
```

This will work I guess... because Foo is castable to IFoo, and ToList returns new list of type specefied.