# Using interface realization thru generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I try to use a interface realization through a generic class. Wondering on some abstraction magic, but get compiler errors with this approach.

```
cannot convert from 'GClass<PosClass>' to 'GClass<IPos>'
```

Here a simplified example:

```cs
//Very simple generic with only data access, no internal manipulation
class GClass<T> {
    T value;
    public GClass(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T Get() {
        return value;
    }
}

//Simple interface
interface IPos {
    int GetPos();
}

//Simple realization
class PosClass : IPos {
    //Interface realization
    public int GetPos() {
        return 1;
    }
    public int GetAnotherImportantData() {
        return -1;
    }
}

class MainTrouble {
    public int DoUsingInterface(GClass<IPos> interfaceableItem) {
        //Do work using only interface methods
        return interfaceableItem.Get().GetPos();
    }

    public int DoUsingInheritance() {
        GClass<PosClass> item = new GClass<PosClass>(new PosClass());
        //Next line error me
        //cannot convert from 'GClass<PosClass>' to 'GClass<IPos>'
        var r = DoUsingInterface(item);
        //So, next I should execute a several methods using PosClass
        return item.Get().GetAnotherImportantData();
    }
}
```

Some suggestions? Maybe some tricky cast which I miss with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works and I'll add an explanation why at the bottom:

```
interface IGClass<out T>
{
    T Get();
}
class GClass<T> : IGClass<T>
{
    T value;
    public GClass(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T Get()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

//Simple interface
interface IPos
{
    int GetPos();
}

//Simple realization
class PosClass : IPos
{
    //Interface realization
    public int GetPos()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public int GetAnotherImportantData()
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

class MainTrouble
{
    public int DoUsingInterface(IGClass<IPos> interfaceableItem)
    {
        //Do work using only interface methods
        return interfaceableItem.Get().GetPos();
    }

    public int DoUsingInheritance()
    {
        GClass<PosClass> item = new GClass<PosClass>(new PosClass());

        var r = DoUsingInterface(item);

        return item.Get().GetAnotherImportantData();
    }
}
```

You want a `GClass<PosClass>` to be a `GClass<IPos>`. *You* know that works, because *you* know that GClass is "readonly". All `PosClass` are `IPos`, but obviously not all `IPos` are `PosClass`. So for the first to work, both would need to be true.

So you need to make sure your compiler knows what *you* know: that your class GClass is effectively read-only. Because then you only need the first part and that's always true. This is where the [`out` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) comes in. It's called [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics) and only works on interfaces, that's why I added an extra interface.

Let's play this through with easier and more graphic examples. A Wolf is an Animal. A sheep is an Animal. But a List of sheep is *not* a list of animals... if it were, I could add a wolf to it, because a wolf is an animal. So what you need is an interface saying "Yes, they are all animals, *on reading*. Like `IEnumerable<T>`. An `IEnumerable<Sheep>` *is* an `IEnumerable<Animal>` because it's declared covariant, which is only possible because it only works in one direction: reading.

Comment: I've always struggled to understand covariance, but I think I see what you're getting at. Is this essentially the list-equivalent of doing something like `IPos myVar = new PosClass();` and then only being able to work with `myVar` as if it were an `IPos` and not a `PosClass()` (since you would need a hard cast for that)?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902209/6060256) addressing a problem not far from yours, it will not work because there is no relation between `GClass<IPos>` and `GClass<PosClass>`. Indeed, a list of `GClass<PosClass>` is not a list of `GClass<IPos>`.

In order to help you understand better those problems, I suggest you to read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index) about covariance and contravariance.